# PHP: regex & hash key in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

How do I address special characters in Regex? `@ ? # $ % %...`
this patten searches for a letter that comes between a prefix and a suffix.

```
$pattern = '/((?<!\b$PREFIX)$LETTER|$LETTER(?!$SUFFIX\b))/i';

$string = 'end'; 

$prefix = 'e';  
$letter = 'n';  
$suffix = 'd';
```

But what if `$string` began with a `#`

```
$string = '#end';
$prefix = ???
```

edit: This is the preg_replace in full

```
$text = "<p>Newton, Einsteing and Edison. #end</p>"
$pattern = '/((?<!\b$PREFIX)$LETTER|$LETTER(?!$SUFFIX\b))/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '<b>\1</b>', $text);
```

this replaces all the `n` letters with a bold `n` but is supposed to exculde the `n` in `#end`

Comment: Ah, the `\b` doesn't work is more the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose your pattern with double quote to make the variables interpolated.

```
$pattern = "/((?<!\b$PREFIX)$LETTER|$LETTER(?!$SUFFIX\b))/i";
```

And more, you define $prefix (lower case) and use $PREFIX (uppercase). So the script becomes the following and works fine for me :

```
<?php
$PREFIX = 'e';  
$LETTER = 'n';  
$SUFFIX = 'd';  
$text = "<p>Newton, Einsteing and Edison. #end</p>";
$pattern = "/((?<!\b$PREFIX)$LETTER|$LETTER(?!$SUFFIX\b))/i";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "<b>$1</b>", $text),"\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
<p><b>N</b>ewto<b>n</b>, Ei<b>n</b>stei<b>n</b>g a<b>n</b>d Ediso<b>n</b>. #end</p>
```

without code formating:

**N**ewto**n**, Ei**n**stei**n**g a**n**d Ediso**n**. #end

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the special chars first with a backslash.
But as the backslash already escape letters in a string, you'll have to escape your backslash first.

```
$string = '\\#end';
```

A better way to do this is to use the [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function on your string, and specify what kind of delimiter you use (here "/").

```
preg_quote($string, '/');
```